# How to handle interdependent queries in transaction?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, transactions

According to the mysqli documentation we can start transaction by calling `$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);`. After setting autocommit to false, new rows would not be inserted to the table untill we commit them manually. Although it is seems a good and simple way to make transactions, It fails in situations a little more complex.

Suppose if we have two tables with a foreign key in the second table that depends on a primary key in the first table. It would not be possible to insert anything in the second table during the transaction because it is the violation of the foreign key policies.
How should I handle these kind of dependencies between the queries through a transaction? Is there any way to commit the queries and then rollback them in case of error in the future?
I know you may say that using insert id is possible in the next queries of transaction but the primary key is not auto increment in my case. It's a unique id coming from outside world.
Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: I dislike clearing autocommit; it is too easy to forget to do COMMIT in a timely manner.  I prefer to explicitly `BEGIN` (or `START`) the transaction as a reminder that I need a `COMMIT`.

Comment: Can't you do the INSERTs in the 'proper' order?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use the keywords:

```
START TRANSACTION [or] BEGIN
COMMIT
ROLLBACK
```

Consult the manual:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html